# Django REST framework relationship owner

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create object using Django REST framework. Everything works fine, except checking relationship's owner. I can insert as a relation row which is not owned by me. Example schema:

## Car:

- id
- name
- category_id
- user_id

## Category:

- id
- name
- user_id

I can insert car with my current user id (it is filled in pre_save), but category id can be any that exists (it don't check user_id of Category). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you're saying that right now you can insert a Car object with any category id, but you want to enforce that any Car object inserted has a category whose user_id is equal to the user_id in the Car object.

One way you can do this validation is by doing [object level validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) in your serializer. Since the validation you want to do depends on values of multiple fields, you want to override the object level validation method in the serializer class for your Car model:

```
def validate(self, data):
    cat_id = data['category_id']
    # You may have to change the below line depending on how user_id is determined
    user_id = self.context['request'].user.id
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)
        if category.user_id != user_id:
            raise ValidationError({'category_id': 'Category must belong to the user'})
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        # Do something
        raise ValidationError({'category_id': 'invalid id'})
    return data
```